# Primefaces js and css resources not loaded with PrimeFaces 4.0 on JBoss EAP 6.4

Tags: maven, jsf, primefaces, jboss-eap-6

We have this application live in production with weblogic 10.3.4 ,JSF( Mojara 2.1.7) and primefaces 4.0. While migration with some configuration and code changes i was able deploy EAR on JBoss EAP 6.4 and then i found this issue of web resources getting failed in the browser console (mainly js and css resouces added by primefaces).Hence the page loads partially with below errors.

```
**Name**                                  **Status**                                   **Type**
homePage.xhtml                                  200                                     document    
primefaces.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=4.0    (failed)                                    stylesheet  
jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=4.0         (failed)                                        script  
jquery-plugins.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=4.0 (failed)net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING    script  
utx.css (failed)    stylesheet  
primefaces.css  (failed)    stylesheet  
theme.css       (failed)    stylesheet  
adminBlue.css   (failed)    stylesheet
```

```
homePage.xhtml:350 Uncaught ReferenceError: PrimeFaces is not defined
    at homePage.xhtml:350

homePage.xhtml:356 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at homePage.xhtml:356

jquery-plugins.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=4.0:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery-plugins.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=4.0:11
```

Libraries are bundled in WEB-INF\lib of each wars. Only the libraries which are provided by jboss as modules i have kept  as scope "provided" in POMs for them. Primefaces-4.0.jar as well is bundled in WEB-INF\lib of each of the wars. JSF in use is of JBOSS EAP 6.4 implemented jsf module mojara-2.1.28.

EAR Structure :

```
|--/META-INF/application.xml
|--/META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml
|--/war1.war 
   |--/WEB-INF/lib
   |--/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
   |--/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml
   |--/WEB-INF/web.xml
|--/war2.war
   |--/WEB-INF/lib
   |--/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
   |--/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml
   |--/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
<ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
        <deployment> 
         <dependencies> 

            <module name="com.oracle.ojdbc" /> 

        </dependencies> 
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.log4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />

        </exclusions>
     </deployment> 
     <sub-deployment name="war1.war">         
         <dependencies> 

              <module name="com.oracle.ojdbc" />                        
         </dependencies> 
           <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.log4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
        </exclusions>
     </sub-deployment> 

     <sub-deployment name="war2.war">         
         <dependencies> 

             <module name="com.oracle.ojdbc" />
         </dependencies> 
           <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.log4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />

        </exclusions>
     </sub-deployment> 
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

POM :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


  <groupId>war1_groupID</groupId>
  <artifactId>war1_ID</artifactId>
  <packaging>war1</packaging>
  <version>1.0 </version> 
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>



  <dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4 </version> 
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.1 </version>
    <scope>provided</scope> 
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
    <version>0.2 </version> 
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1 </version> 


</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.4 </version> 
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.1 </version> 

</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.0 </version> <scope>provided</scope>

</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1 </version> 
     <scope>provided</scope>

</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2 </version> 
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

     <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7 </version> 
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>



<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7 </version> 
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0 </version> 
    <scope>provided</scope>

</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1 </version> 
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0 </version> 

</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0 </version>

</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.7 </version>

</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2 </version> 

</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8 </version> 
     <scope>provided</scope>    

</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2 </version> 
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>



<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3 </version> 
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>4.0 </version> 

</dependency>



 <dependency> 
  <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>3.0 </version> 
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.3 </version> 
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>






<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0 </version> 
  <scope>provided</scope>

</dependency>



  </dependencies>

  <build>

    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2 </version> 
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>

       <configuration>

        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>APP-INF/lib/</classpathPrefix>         
        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
        </manifest>
        <archive>
           <manifestEntries>
            <Specification-Title>FRM</Specification-Title>
            <Specification-Version>Redesign</Specification-Version>
            <Implementation-Version>${release.number}</Implementation-Version>
           </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration> 


      </plugin> 
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Namespaces on xhtml :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

Logs prints JBOSS implemented Mojarra -2.1.28:

```
10:41:42,972 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.4.15.GA (AS 7.5.15.Final-redhat-3) starting
10:41:43,048 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO Version 3.0.16.GA-redhat-1
10:41:43,054 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.16.GA-redhat-1
10:41:43,071 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBoss Remoting version 3.3.9.Final-redhat-1
10:42:00,484 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) JBAS010153: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
10:42:00,501 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS013371: Activating Security Subsystem
10:42:00,506 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
10:42:00,536 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
10:42:00,521 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
10:42:00,548 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
10:42:00,573 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) JBAS016300: Activating JacORB Subsystem
10:42:00,583 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
10:42:00,570 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS013370: Current PicketBox version=4.1.5.Final-redhat-1
10:42:00,594 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBAS012615: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main, 1.2]
10:42:00,742 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.0.38.Final-redhat-3)
10:42:00,742 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
10:42:00,744 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
10:42:00,764 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 11.2)
10:42:00,869 INFO  [org.jboss.jaxr] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS014000: Started JAXR subsystem, binding JAXR connection factory into JNDI as: java:jboss/jaxr/ConnectionFactory
10:42:01,181 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWEB001065: The native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
10:42:01,308 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-10.40.32.154:8080
10:42:01,344 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-10.40.32.154:8080
10:42:01,378 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.3.6.Final-redhat-1
10:42:01,367 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) HQ221000: live server is starting with configuration HornetQ Configuration (clustered=false,backup=false,sharedStore=true,journalDirectory=/app/jboss-eap-6.4/domain/servers/Server_1/data/messagingjournal,bindingsDirectory=/app/jboss-eap-6.4/domain/servers/Server_1/data/messagingbindings,largeMessagesDirectory=/app/jboss-eap-6.4/domain/servers/Server_1/data/messaginglargemessages,pagingDirectory=/app/jboss-eap-6.4/domain/servers/Server_1/data/messagingpaging)
10:42:01,381 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) HQ221006: Waiting to obtain live lock
10:42:01,410 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS016330: CORBA ORB Service started
10:42:01,423 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) HQ221013: Using NIO Journal
10:42:01,479 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) HQ221034: Waiting to obtain live lock
10:42:01,479 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) HQ221035: Live Server Obtained live lock
10:42:01,759 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) HQ221020: Started Netty Acceptor version 3.6.10.Final-266dbdf 10.40.32.154:5445 for CORE protocol
10:42:01,765 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) HQ221020: Started Netty Acceptor version 3.6.10.Final-266dbdf 10.40.32.154:5455 for CORE protocol
10:42:01,768 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) HQ221007: Server is now live
10:42:01,768 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) HQ221001: HornetQ Server version 2.3.25.SP18 (2.3.25.SP18, 123) [a90888a3-643e-11ea-a637-39e0628d872d] 
10:42:01,793 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
10:42:01,802 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.DLQ
10:42:01,813 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/jms/queue/DLQ
10:42:01,814 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
10:42:01,815 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue
10:42:01,816 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
10:42:18,219 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010406: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
10:42:18,258 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra] (MSC service thread 1-1) HornetQ resource adaptor started
10:42:18,259 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-1) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatorhornetq-ra
10:42:18,261 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010401: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
10:42:35,425 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS016328: CORBA Naming Service started
10:43:08,463 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver (version 1.0)
10:43:08,469 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 42.0)
10:43:08,473 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 42.0)
10:43:08,477 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 42.1)
10:43:08,480 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.edb.Driver (version 9.2)
10:43:08,526 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/JDBCDataSource1]
10:43:08,528 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/JDBCDataSource2]
10:43:08,527 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on 10.40.32.154:4447
10:43:08,530 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "EAR.ear" (runtime-name: "EAR.ear")
10:43:09,129 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015973: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "War1.war")
10:43:09,130 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015973: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "War2.war")
10:43:09,425 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015852: Could not index class javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility$1NullInputStream.class at /content/EAR.ear/War1.war/WEB-INF/lib/webserviceclient-10.3.4.jar: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197) [rt.jar:1.8.0_242]
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169) [rt.jar:1.8.0_242]
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.verifyMagic(Indexer.java:441) [jandex-1.2.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.2.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:697) [jandex-1.2.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.2.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:100) [jboss-as-server-7.5.15.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(AnnotationIndexProcessor.java:51) [jboss-as-server-7.5.15.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:177) [jboss-as-server-7.5.15.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2064) [jboss-msc-1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1.jar:1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1987) [jboss-msc-1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1.jar:1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_242]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_242]

10:43:09,437 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015852: Could not index class weblogic/utils/classloaders/ClasspathClassFinder$ZipFileWrapper.class at /content/EAR.ear/War1.war/WEB-INF/lib/webserviceclient-10.3.4.jar: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197) [rt.jar:1.8.0_242]
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169) [rt.jar:1.8.0_242]
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.verifyMagic(Indexer.java:441) [jandex-1.2.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.2.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:697) [jandex-1.2.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.2.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:100) [jboss-as-server-7.5.15.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(AnnotationIndexProcessor.java:51) [jboss-as-server-7.5.15.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:177) [jboss-as-server-7.5.15.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2064) [jboss-msc-1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1.jar:1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1987) [jboss-msc-1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1.jar:1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_242]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_242]

10:43:09,456 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015852: Could not index class javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility$1NullInputStream.class at /content/EAR.ear/War2.war/WEB-INF/lib/webserviceclient-10.3.4.jar: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197) [rt.jar:1.8.0_242]
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169) [rt.jar:1.8.0_242]
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.verifyMagic(Indexer.java:441) [jandex-1.2.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.2.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:697) [jandex-1.2.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.2.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:100) [jboss-as-server-7.5.15.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(AnnotationIndexProcessor.java:51) [jboss-as-server-7.5.15.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:177) [jboss-as-server-7.5.15.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2064) [jboss-msc-1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1.jar:1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1987) [jboss-msc-1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1.jar:1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_242]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_242]

10:43:09,465 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015852: Could not index class weblogic/utils/classloaders/ClasspathClassFinder$ZipFileWrapper.class at /content/EAR.ear/War2.war/WEB-INF/lib/webserviceclient-10.3.4.jar: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197) [rt.jar:1.8.0_242]
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169) [rt.jar:1.8.0_242]
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.verifyMagic(Indexer.java:441) [jandex-1.2.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.2.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:697) [jandex-1.2.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.2.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:100) [jboss-as-server-7.5.15.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(AnnotationIndexProcessor.java:51) [jboss-as-server-7.5.15.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:177) [jboss-as-server-7.5.15.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2064) [jboss-msc-1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1.jar:1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1987) [jboss-msc-1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1.jar:1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_242]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_242]

10:43:10,977 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) JBAS018210: Register web context: /context1
10:43:10,977 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) JBAS018210: Register web context: /context2
10:43:11,001 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) JBWEB001093: The listener com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener is already configured for this context, the duplicate definition has been ignored
10:43:11,005 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) JBWEB001093: The listener com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener is already configured for this context, the duplicate definition has been ignored
10:43:28,235 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) **Initializing Mojarra 2.1.28.SP11**  for context '/context1'
10:43:28,241 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) **Initializing Mojarra 2.1.28.SP11**  for context '/context2'
10:43:28,759 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.3.Final-redhat-1
10:43:29,360 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) **Running on PrimeFaces 4.0**
10:43:29,360 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) Running on PrimeFaces 4.0
10:44:04,563 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015859: Deployed "EAR.ear" (runtime-name : "EAR.ear")
10:44:04,584 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.4.15.GA (AS 7.5.15.Final-redhat-3) started in 142266ms - Started 508 of 545
```

Hope the details suffice. Thanks

Comment: @Kukeltje , i tried but end up having errors pertaining to primefaces css and js in browser console.Now i m trying to find out the root cause as to why the primefaces resources are failing to load with no response.

Comment: And tried with different browsers?

Comment: @Kukeltje edited. yes , i tried with  MF as well.

Comment: yes chrome ,Mozilla firefox and internet explorer as well.

Comment: Ahhhhh.... I usually abbreviate (Mozilla) FireFox to FF ;-)

Comment: Do you have any significant/related log of your server startup? Have you tried with EAP 6.4 but old Mojarra jar? I mean, in your pom.xml you have `<artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>` but JBoss uses another version, do you override the module?
    <version>2.1.7 </version>

Comment: @WoAiNii, yes server startup logs i have attached above. also i have added that jsf-impl artifact in POM with scope as provided so it wont bundle the jar in wars. In that case jboss implemented mojara version will be added which it prints in logs i have added above - "Initializing Mojarra 2.1.28.SP11". I didnt go for using older version of mojara as i m using primefaces-4.0.

Comment: Have you tried with just one war within your ear? Do these two libs folders overlaps, for any jars? Have you tried to move these on one folder at ear level?

Comment: earlier , all the libs were in APP-INF/lib then i was facing noclaasfounderror so i removed them from ear and kept it in web-inf/lib .And for the two libs folder overlapping i think the "<ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated" entry in jboss-deployment-structure.xml will prevent it , if m not wrong??

Comment: Still simplify... Narrow down... Try with a war without any ear etc... And are there any errors in the jboss server log? Do you have a proxy in between? What is the http response code? .. etc...

Comment: there's no error in server logs but in the browser console. peimefaces and jquery requests are being failed as below in header section under Network tab >>>Request URL: https://example.com/context/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=4.0
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK   and the response has no data. In network and console tab i get the errors i mentioned in the post at the top.

Comment: I have one more finding that these errors are occuring only when i access the app through  URL (web to app server) but when idirectly hit the application through appServer IP:port/context there is no such errors.